# Problem with Remmina after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, remmina

Remmina broke down after upgrade - wouldn't launch saying some library is missing. So I decided to reinstall it, but

```
sudo apt install remmina
```

Results in

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 remmina : Depends: remmina-common (= 1.4.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1.4.7+ppa202007310937.r9798b07.df03f7ba~ubuntu18.04.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: remmina-plugin-rdp but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: remmina-plugin-vnc but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: remmina-plugin-secret but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is it not possible to install remmina using apt on 20.04? I prefer it over snap version, because I couldn't find a way to make the snap version of Remmina to open .rdp files.

Edit: I did

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

After which I was finally able to install using apt. However it won't launch. When I try to run it through terminal, I get the following output:

```
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has registered but not yet initialized/activated. Initialization order is 2000.
Remmina plugin kwallet (type=Secret) has registered but not yet initialized/activated. Initialization order is 1000.
Secret plugin glibsecret has been successfully initialized and will be your default secret plugin
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Remmina homepage:

**Remmina will no longer be available as a PPA package after the release of version 1.4.8.**

Installing from snap worked for me.

```
$ snap install remmina
> remmina v1.4.8+git10.2058366a from Remmina Upstream Developers (remmina✓) installed
$ sudo snap connect remmina:avahi-observe :avahi-observe # servers discovery
$ sudo snap connect remmina:cups-control :cups-control # printing
$ sudo snap connect remmina:mount-observe :mount-observe # mount management
$ sudo snap connect remmina:password-manager-service :password-manager-service # password manager
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is weirding me out beyond being weirded out, but it somehow fixed itself.
The first part of the problem was fixed by cleaning leftover packages with

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

As for the second part, I am now not sure whether there was a problem in the first place or not. I opened a .remmina file from the .local/share/remmina folder and it worked just fine after which the app started running fine from both the terminal and the app tray. My guess is it launched correctly the first time I tried to run it, but the window didn't open on top of all the other apps, so I didn't notice.